# Cannot enable openssl extension for Composer after trying everything for hours! =(

Tags: openssl, composer-php, wamp, php-openssl

When I try to use composer in command line, it keeps saying:

> "[Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
>     The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true."

I did hours of research and tried basically everything I found, including:
- uncommenting extension=php_openssl.dll`and`extension_dir = "ext"`in`php.ini` in all my wamp and stand-alone php folders. I even did that to the phpforApache files.
- making composer use both my stand-alone php AND wamp php (both ver 7.0)
- ticking ssl_module in wamp Apache modules and php_openssl in PHP extensions
- I checked. php_openssl.dll DOES exist in the /ext directory
- I checked and the extension in php.ini does lead to the right directory:   extension_dir ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/"
- Copying libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from installdir/php/ to installdir/apache2/bin/
- reinstalling composer and wamp

What else can I possibly do?? I am pretty desperate now. I tried disabling tls but after that it banned me from connecting: " [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Your configuration does not allow connections to http://packagist.org/packages.json. See https://getcomposer.org/do
  c/06-config.md#secure-http for details."

Help! Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: UPDATE: it works when I switched to Gitbash rather than Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

or you may update your php version to php 7.x

Comment: Please note that "code only" answer are discouraged. Always consider adding a few words of explanations.